# Draw grid with points

Tags: plotting, grid-layouts, drawing, dot

How would I draw a grid with dots on specified intersections? The image below shows the basic idea:

[image]

If I wanted to label the grid lines with index numbers or letters, how would I do that?

Comment: Use Graphics[],Line[],Point[] ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GridLines` and `Ticks` should prove useful.

```
Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[{10, 20}]}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[0, 25], Range[0, 25]},
 Ticks -> {{{5, "A"}, {10, "B"}, {15, "C"}, {20, "D"}}, Automatic},
 PlotRange -> { {0, 25}, {0, 25}}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: grid]